# Can't scroll through a div more than once | Selenium | Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

When I run this, it only manages to scroll down once, and it throws a "Message: element not interactable" error. (it's supposed to scroll twice). When I tried to run it in a loop (made a try and except to ignore the error), and scrolled around with it manually, it would keep pushing me back up to a specific position. But that's strange, because I'm using arrow keys here, not a move to element:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.sl.find_element_by_id('my-id')).perform()
```

I've tried: giving everything more time to load with sleep, hovering over the element and clicking it to make it interactable, using other methods to scroll such as this one and others like it: `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")`

I'm very lost at this point, don't know what to do

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from random import *
import random, json, selenium, os.path, os


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/apple/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://instagram.com')

sleep(7)

username_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
username_form.clear()
username_form.send_keys('ENTER INSTA USER HERE')

password_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
password_form.clear()
password_form.send_keys('ENTER INSTA PASS HERE')

button_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button')
try:
    button_click.click()
except:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_click)

sleep(4)

driver.get('https://instagram.com/p/CQ_sfAeFl5s/')

sleep(4)

like_meter = driver.find_element_by_class_name('zV_Nj')
like_meter.click()

sleep(1)

try:
    scroll_zone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div')
except:
    scroll_zone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div')


scroll_zone.click()

sleep(0.5)

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(scroll_zone)
hover.perform()

sleep(0.5)

scroll_zone.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
scroll_zone.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

Comment: Q1: Which line and element are throwing "not interactable"? Q2: Why do you expect it to scroll twice? I only see one move_to_element in your code.

Comment: Have you tried `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", scroll_zone)` ?

Comment: Do not forget to accept answers if they answer your questions.

Comment: @ConradAlbrecht The not interactable error happens when i scroll the first time with: `scroll_zone.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)`, but it still scrolls for some odd reason. Also that move_to_element is just the hover, it is my attempt to make it interactable . Yes, @Burakudo i've tried that

Comment: @Burakudo nvm that worked again after i tried it again, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll that list of persons liked that page you can do this:

```
like_meter = driver.find_element_by_class_name('zV_Nj')
like_meter.click()

sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[role='dialog'] div[style*='padding']")

for n in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollDown += 20", elem)
```

The range of 10 and 20 pixels scrolling can be changed according to your needs

Comment: ummm i don't think this line is pythonic `JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;`

Comment: Sorry, it's from Java. Will try to give it in Python soon

Comment: it would be awesome if you could. I assume you are trying to execute JS here, we do that like this: `driver.execute_script()`. The driver being the chrome driver. I tried this but didn't work for some reason

Comment: I'm not really familiar with JavaScript. Please let me know if this works

Comment: didn't work, didn't give me any errors either

Comment: Hey man found the solution, you might as well post it up so others can find it. I used the scrollintoview command (I did it wrong the first time around, the code is `while True:
    sleep(1)

    prof = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[11]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", prof)`

Comment: Just format it properly, it basiclly loads the profiles until it breaks, Instagram loads 11 profiles at a time. So this finds the 11th profile scrolls to it, which then loads in the next 11 (and so on). Thank you for taking the time to help out with this one mate

Comment: Lemme know when you edit the code in so i can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: First of all thank you very much for helping me with a better solution. This really makes me happy. However I'm not sure about this approach. You can not loop on that element. You simply found some element that is initially out of the view and scrolling it into the view. That's correct. But what about the next loop iteration? It is already in the view. Or do you mean to iterate over those elements in the list and scroll each one of them into the view? This can be an idea. Not sure, lets try. I will write this and you will check if it worked. I can't debug this on my computer.

Comment: I'll do that later.

Comment: You might of misunderstood my explanation. When you scroll the prof element into view and try to find it again, another set of profiles has been loaded in. So with the second iteration and all the iteration after, it's a new set of 11 profiles each time. I assume Insta does this to save up on space and loading speed. To summerize, each time you scroll the element into view, the element is now the xpath of another IG profile. But try it out, it worked for me.

Comment: Now I understand. You are right.  But what is the case to exit the while loop in the code you posted above? Do you have it or need my help with that?